# How to create contour lines from TIFF (raster with more than 100 bands)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, contour, batch

I need to do batch processing from a raster with 120 bands (GeoTIFF). I need 120 contour line shapefiles, but I get only one. I had no problem when the result is another raster file with all the bands, but the contour line is a shapefile, I don´t know if this is the problem...

Comment: You need to either generate contours from one band, or save each band to a temporary raster, and generate a contour from that.

Answer (score 4):

with the commanline tool [gdal_contour](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html) you can choose from which band the contour lines shall be created. In this example band `42`:

```
gdal_contour -a elev dem.tif contour_band_42.shp -i 10.0 -b 42
```

This can be integrated in a batch file. On Unix it should be something like this:

```
for BAND in {1..120} 
do
  gdal_contour -a elev dem.tif contour_band_${BAND}.shp -i 10.0 -b ${BAND}
done
```

Comment: Thanks Jakob, It sounds correct, but is not posible to edit GDAL console. I try to run in python console the script but it dosen´t work, neither the one that GDAL create for one band

Comment: which operating system are you using? 
On Windows you have the GDAL commandline tools inside the [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) shell. There the syntax for the for loop might be slightly different than in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!! Thanks